# Appending pairs of coordinates to numpy array

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I need to append 1D arrays (coordinates) into a 2d array using `numpy` in python 3.6.

I can do this with lists using append, such as in the first example below.

```
mastlist =[]
i=0
for i in  range (10):
    i=i+1
    coor = []
    xcoor = i
    ycoor =i*2
    coor.append(xcoor)
    coor.append(ycoor)
    mastlist.append(coor)
print(mastlist)
```

But I want a more performant approach using `numpy` arrays. When I attempt to convert the list approach to an array (second example),

```
import numpy as np
i=0
for i in  range (10):
    i=i+1
    centroid =np.append(i,i*2)
    masterarray=np.append([centroid],axis=0)
    print(masterarray)

print(masterarray)
```

I get the error below.

My error is:

> TypeError: append() missing 1 required positional argument: 'values'

I would of expected an array such as:

```
[[1, 2], [2, 4], [3, 6], [4, 8], [5, 10], [6, 12], [7, 14], [8, 16], [9, 18], [10, 20]]
```

I have also fumbled with attempts using `extend`, `vstack`, and `concatenate`.

Any advice would be welcome.

Comment: list append is better than repeated numpy concatenate.  It's faster and easier to get right.

Comment: minor cleanup `mastlist.append([xcoor,ycoor])`

Comment: Are centroid values always concecutive, `np.arange(10)` and *2?

Comment: centroid values aren't always concecuitive and *2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just use list comprehension?

```
import numpy as np

masterarray = np.array([[i,2*i] for i in range(1,11)])
```

**output**

```
array([[ 1,  2],
       [ 2,  4],
       [ 3,  6],
       [ 4,  8],
       [ 5, 10],
       [ 6, 12],
       [ 7, 14],
       [ 8, 16],
       [ 9, 18],
       [10, 20]])
```

Comment: I don't think list comprehension would work in my "real life" application, as  the coordinates (x,y) won't be produced from an expression in a loop.

Comment: Then, your question is not consistent with your "real life" application. ;)

Answer (score 3):

I recommend you get single coordinate data firstly , then concatenate them. To my best knowledge, I dont think it can be done by np.append

The common method is [np.concatenate](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html#numpy.concatenate), which I see it from cs231n class.

My sample codes are as follows:

```py
import numpy as np
xcoor = np.arange(1,11,1).reshape(-1,1)
ycoor = np.arange(2,22,2).reshape(-1,1)
xycoor = np.concatenate((xcoor,ycoor),axis = 1)
print(xycoor)
```

Output:

```py
[[ 1  2]
 [ 2  4]
 [ 3  6]
 [ 4  8]
 [ 5 10]
 [ 6 12]
 [ 7 14]
 [ 8 16]
 [ 9 18]
 [10 20]]
```